# Pycharm - Running Open CV Code goes straight to "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)"

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

I am trying to run open-cv code to get access to my webcam in a python script. However, when I try to run it I get "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)" every time I try to run it. There is no error in my code and I also looked at other posts to add the environment variables: `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL=NO;PYTHONMALLOC=debug`
My code is:

```
import cv2

# define a video capture object 
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while (True):
    # Capture the video frame
    # by frame
    ret, frame = vid.read()

    # display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    # the 'q button is set as the
    # quitting button
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    # after the loop realse the cap object
    vid.release()
    # destroy all windows
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

Last two lines must be outside while loop:

```
import cv2

# define a video capture object 
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while (True):
    # Capture the video frame
    # by frame
    ret, frame = vid.read()

    # display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    # the 'q button is set as the
    # quitting button
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# after the loop realse the cap object
vid.release()
# destroy all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: To add to Sarims answer. SIGSEGV is a memory access violation, I find this error a lot when using code that comes from a c++ library. Essentially you are trying to access a reference to an object that has been deleted.

Comment: Ok, i will do that

Comment: @LewisMorris do you think it is because of my environment variables. I know I changed them the other day to follow someone else's solution however it didn't work. Should I just change them back to normal?

Comment: It could be but then why would it work in jupyter and not pycharm. It's a odd one. You will have more luck in the openCv forums. Maybe a bit of a slower response though.

Comment: Ok thank you @LewisMorris , I just did it : https://answers.opencv.org/question/233810/pycharm-python-process-finished-with-exit-code-139-interrupted-by-signal-11-sigsegv/

Answer (score 1):

To add to this.

SIGSEGV is a memory access violation, I find this error a lot when using code that comes from a c++ library. Essentially you are trying to access a object in memory that has been deleted but the reference to it still remains.

When you call these

```
`# after the loop realse the cap object
vid.release()
# destroy all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Opencv must essentially be deleting the object in the memory.

Then when you do the next iteration of your while loop you try to access them with this.

```
`ret, frame = vid.read()

# display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('frame', frame)`
```

But the video capture object and the window are not there (but the reference to the python object remains).

And then boom, crash . Because it fails to find the object and doesn't know what to do.